# HP Omen 15 - ek0010ca - audio issues

Tags: sound, alsa, hp, 21.10

Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS - Realtek ALC245 - uses SOF. This is going to be just a briefly cleaned up version of my notes.

I'm hoping someone has had this issue and can help, I have been plodding away trying to figure it out to no avail. All of my searches has not brought up anything that really matches my issue.

When using the GNOME control center sound test, audio is delayed/broken on both sides, I'll hear a "t left" or "front" for example. Looking at the output bar, I can see the full audio being played. The audio is just not being output right, at the speakers.

> `speaker-test` -> audio sounds normal, reports playing out Front Left
> channel, but audio is coming out of both speakers
>
> `speaker-test -c2` -> Front Left channel has skipping audio at regular
> intervals (1s on, 1s off), Front Right channel has skipping audio at
> regular intervals (1s on, 1s off)
>
> `speaker-test -c2 -s1` -> Front Left  channel has skipping audio at
> regular intervals (1s on, 1s off) out of the left speaker

Playing a video or game, audio sounds correct, move balance to left and the audio skips, move the audio to the right and it skips. As long as the balance is centered, the audio plays correct. However, there is a delay to the audio start, this is noticeable in Minecraft. If 0 sounds are playing (according to the debug), and I make a sound occur, it is silent. If I don't delay and keep making the sound (e.g. mining) the sound starts. If I wait 10 seconds, the behaviour repeats.

- Tried Pulseaudio and Pipewire, both exhibit the behaviour
- Tried multiple Linux distros (ArchCraft, Axyl, Pop!_OS, Ubuntu, Manjaro), issue follows
- For Pop!_OS 21.10 and Ubuntu 21.10, kernels are 5.15 and 5.13 respectively, both exhibit the behaviour. Axyl had the bleeding edge kernel in the 5.16 series, issue still present
- Complete shutdown of Pulseaudio (and confirmed it was not running), and used speaker-test directly with ALSA, issue was still present
- Since the I took Pulseaudio out of the formula, commenting out module-suspend-on-idle does not help
- Disabling power saving does not help
- Laptop has Bang & Olufsen speaker setup (not sure if that really matters)
- Audio works as intended in Windows 10

Output of `curl https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/raw/master/src/utils/pa-info?inline=false | bash | nc termbin.com 9999` ----> [Termbin link](https://termbin.com/3puw)

```
> lspci -v
  
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 179, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 6044110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6044000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU116 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at 78080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
    
> cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x78080000 irq 17
 1 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      HP-OMENLaptop15_ek0xxx--878A

> dmesg | grep snd

[   34.251943] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[   34.251963] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   34.252033] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   34.252125] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   34.252130] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   34.342178] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: bound 0000:01:00.0 (ops nv50_audio_component_bind_ops [nouveau])
[   35.645366] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: autoconfig for ALC245: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   35.645368] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   35.645369] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   35.645370] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   35.645371] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    inputs:
[   35.645372] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:      Mic=0x19
[   35.691746] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: sink widget AIF1TX overwritten
[   35.691749] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source widget AIF1RX overwritten

> dmesg | grep sof

[   35.054556] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[   35.054574] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   35.054586] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   35.054722] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[   35.054775] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   35.061729] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[   35.355175] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[   35.355177] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[   35.355181] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
[   35.582605] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:6:0-18fab
[   35.582607] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:17:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
[   35.608445] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:17:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
[   35.625794] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
[   35.703633] input: sof-hda-dsp Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input30
[   35.703679] input: sof-hda-dsp Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input31
[   35.703702] input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input32
[   35.703722] input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input33
[   35.703762] input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same laptop model and am experiencing the same problem with clipped audio when playing audio books/podcasts or listening to anything speech related. Sure is annoying as hell. Tried all suggested solutions from the web with no result so far.

However I've found a simple solution to this problem. Simply play a background sound, such as calm ambient songs at low volume.

It seems the speech pauses between words caused the audio subsystem to prematurely stop and then to start again at the beginning of the next word, at a slight delay, causing the word to be clipped. By playing the background song, even at low volume will keep the audio subsystem to remain continuously active/open. Good luck.

Comment: @Scientist - It looks like a valid answer (even if a workaround) to me.

Comment: I agree, it is the most valid for the issue even if it is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Volume Control for PulseAudio**

PulseAudio is a default sound service for Ubuntu as well as a few others. It’s open source and generally reliable, working with ALSA and OSS drivers to make sure the sound signals your system generates get passed on to your speakers.
[image: Ubuntu Sound Not Working Pavucontrol Volume Control]

But while applications and desktop environments come with their own volume controls for PulseAudio, it’s not that granular and doesn’t let you control each playback stream individually. Pavucontrol gives you more control over each audio device on your PC, so you can play around with those sliders to make sure that your speaker or headphone volume is set to what it should be, for instance.

To install pavucontrol, open the Terminal and enter the following commands:

```
pulseaudio --start
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

After that, run pavucontrol either from the terminal or looking up “PulseAudio Volume Control” in your desktop environment’s launch menu. Go to the “Output Devices” tab and make sure your default speakers are selected.

**Reload ALSA**

Another thing you can try if the sound issue persists is to reload ALSA. To do that, use the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

The output looks like the following image.

[image: ubuntu-sound-issue-3]

Once it’s done, if you still have trouble getting the sound working, try

```
pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D
```

You may have trouble after reloading ALSA if pulseaudio does not register that the modules were reloaded.

If you’re still not getting audio, try this one-shot ALSA command directly:

```
alsactl restore
```